# change SqlDataSource connection string in asp.net dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in asp.net (web forms) that up until now only had one database for data.

So all the controls that require something from the database use a datasource and the same connection string.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString %>" 
                    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT ... ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Up until now I only needed one connection string since I had only one database but this has changed since I want some users to connect to database A and others to database B

What would be the correct way to go about it? Preferably without many changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it programatically after you determine which one you want to use, i.e.

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "whateveryouwant";
```

It doesn't have to be set inline in the control.

Comment: when in the page life cycle would be the best time to do this? I had this way as a backup since I have to go searching for all the sqlDataSources and changing them by hand.

Comment: Where will you be determining user info? Most likely after that, could be at the application level in Global.asax at Session Start? or at the page level at Page_Load, not sure of your design so just throwing out suggestions :)

Comment: I have the default asp.net membership (in a 3rd DB) so when the user logs in depending on some parameters I can find out what database he should belong. It's my first site so I don't know much about Global.asax or anything like that... could you give some links maybe?

Comment: Hmm if you have a membership DB, could you check the role if you have assigned them? like User.IsInRole? Also here is an older article but covers global.asax events http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5771721.html

Comment: so... I should have the datasources get the connection string from Global.asax where I can change it once the user authenticates himself and then it would be correct?

Comment: That is one option, The Session_OnStart indicates the event when the user establishes a session with your web application, here you could check different things about the user, using the Roles mechanism of your membership provider, you could also set a Session variable like "userConnection" and then reference Session["userConnection"] as their connection string for all your connections, this is probably not the cleanest approach and there are some issues with sessions and scaling, but since this seems to be your first app, it will be a good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

On your page you have SqlDataSource1, and also in your web.config you should have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConectionString" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
</connectionStrings>
```

To add the connection string to your SqlDatasource1,  in code behind (cs file) use the following code in onliad methot:

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Hello! Could you please add more context or an explanation for your answer?

Comment: On your page you have SqlDataSource1, and also in your web.config you should have:
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConectionString" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
  </connectionStrings>`
and to add connection string to your  SqlDatasource1 you use code from above.