# Use Connection Strings in the aspx page from the MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have had to implement a custom connection string handler for my asp.net project.
They are stored normally in the web.config file, however, depending on the host header of the page it could be one of 5 connection strings. What I did was build a custom class to look at the host header and store the desired connection string  in the master page via a [SESSION_VARIABLE]. In the page's .cs file I can access it with Master.conString, however I have discovered many pages where a GridView is bound to a datasource with sort, paging, edit, and delete enabled.

It would be no small chore to convert them all to the code page and recreate every event in C#, so I would really rather find a way around it.

So how can I take:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        DataSourceMode="DataSet"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:i_v2ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [Carrier]FROM [Orders_Carriers] ORDER BY [Carrier]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Orders_Carriers]  SET Carrier=@Carrier WHERE id=@id"
        OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Orders_Carriers] WHERE id=@id"
        OnDeleting="OnRecordDeleting"
        OnDeleted="OnRecordDeleted"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Orders_Carriers] ([Carrier]) VALUES (@Carrier">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and change

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:i_v2ConnectionString %>"
```

to use Master.conString instead.

The value stored in Master.conString is a string value "i_v2ConnectionString".

I should add that I get "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." error if I do:

```
ConnectionString="<%# Eval(Master.conString) %>"
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2949671/690329).

Comment: I didn't realize you could skip the ConnectionString Parameter asp side....